# How to solve this problem Module 'image_picker' not found on Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

When I try to archive my app to upload on the Apple Store I face this problem Module `image_picker` not found?

[image: sample code]

What should I do to fix this `@import` error?

Comment: Did you open ```Runner.xcodeproj``` or ```Runner.xcworkspace``` using xCode ?

Comment: Which is the difference about open the Runner.xcodeproj or Runner.xcworkspace, because i'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

I know that is old topic, but i have a propossiton how you can resolve this issue .

If application is develope in Flutter, and this error occured when you opened project in XCode then you try open entire folder "ios" instead of "xcodeproj" or "xcworkspace".

The tip in the picture below.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfSbc.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31069940)

Comment: today it help me

Answer (score 1):

Verify `info.plist`

iOS #
Add the following keys to your `Info.plist` file, located in `<project root>/ios/Runner/Info.plist`:

`NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` - describe why your app needs permission for the photo library. This is called Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description in the visual editor.

`NSCameraUsageDescription` - describe why your app needs access to the camera. This is called Privacy - Camera Usage Description in the visual editor.

`NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` - describe why your app needs access to the microphone, if you intend to record videos. This is called Privacy - Microphone Usage Description in the visual editor

More detail in: https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

Comment: check the podfile

# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can try running the following commands:

```
pods repo update
rm -rf ios/Pods ios/Podfile.lock
flutter clean
flutter run
```

After that, you have to open the "Runner.xcworkspace" on Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I know is an old topic but could help other people. You need to change "image_picker" to "image_picker_ios" and if this doesn't help, you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72515674/11972105

Answer (score 0):

After 24 hours of trying every solution available on Google, and cleaning flutter for hundreds of times, suddenly a flutter clean worked, very strange.