# Flutter iOS Build Error - framework image_picker not found

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

I have added v0.8.5 of [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) library in my project.

I have tried following things to solve the issue:

```
Deleted podfile.lock & Pods folder from iOS Directory
Deleted pubspec.lock file from Project Directory
pod deintegrate
flutter clean
flutter pub get
pod install
```

While building the project in iOS,It throws following error

```
ld: framework not found image_picker
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can anyone provide a solution to this?

Comment: Do you have a physical iphone or are you using a simulator?

Comment: @muragekibicho I am using iPhone Simulator

Comment: Try this way. Clear derived data first. flutter clean, flutter pub get, flutter pub upgrade, cd ios, pod install , pod upgrade and check

Comment: @HardikMehta Downgrading image_picker Library worked for me.

Comment: Same issue for me with `Error (Xcode): Framework not found image_picker` for building the ios release

Comment: you solved it? a

Answer (score 3):

for me change to image_picker: 0.8.0
after that,

1. flutter clean,
2. flutter pub get
3. cd ios
4. pod deintegrate; pod install

Comment: It worked 100% succesfully.

Answer (score 3):

Due to the latest update, which includes migration of image_picker to Android and iOS federation packages, the naming convention of the iOS package has changed from **"image_picker"** to **"image_picker_ios"**.

**Solution:**

Just make sure that in xcode, your app's project and target linker flags are set from **"image_picker"** to **"image_picker_ios"**.

1. Navigate to xcode project, and then **build settings**
2. Find section **Linking** and then **Other linking flags**.
3. Change flag **-framework "image_picker"** to **-framework "image_picker_ios"**

Important: changes must be applied to both project and target linker flags.

Answer (score 0):

Open **Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj** and change **image_picker** to **image_picker_ios** in all places.